# How to add a constant to all cells in a column excel?

Tags: excel

```
  A
0
0.001
0.002
0.003
0.004
```

I want to add 1.5 to each cell of column A and output is:

```
  A
1.5
1.501
1.502
1.503
1.504
```

Comment: Add 1.5 to all rows in A column and return back also a column.

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried?

Comment: I have indented your input and output sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Also you need to post your code.

Comment: Do you want to do this by hand formula as my answer below describes, or were you trying to code an Excel macro which does this?

Comment: Well there are many ways. So much of determining the best approach for you depends on why you want to and how often you expect to do this. The long term goal. All the cells being contiguous is a big help though. You could use a simple formula as in posted answer. Or do a paste special values & addition. Or assorted VBA logic.

Comment: You mean that you want to show a result of formula by using a COLUMN in that own COLUMN ?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try doing the following:

Enter `1.5` into cell `C1`.  Then enter into cell `B1` the following formula: `= A1 + $C$1`

Next, copy cell `B1` and paste into cells `B2` through `B5`.  Now your worksheet should look like the following:

```
---------------------------------
  |    A    |    B    |    C    |
---------------------------------
1 |       0 |     1.5 |     1.5 |
---------------------------------
2 |   0.001 |   1.501 |         |
---------------------------------
3 |   0.002 |   1.502 |         |
---------------------------------
4 |   0.003 |   1.503 |         |
---------------------------------
5 |   0.004 |   1.504 |         |
---------------------------------
```

By referring to cell `C1` as `$C$1`, Excel will treat it as a constant to be applied to the formula of every cell in which it appears, in contrast to the source column A.

Answer (score 38):

- Enter the value into a cell.
- Copy the cell.
- Select all relevant cells in column A
- Click Paste Special, in the dialog tick "Add" and hit OK.

Comment: Google now shows this answer in a quick view card.